# Roots of $e^z - z - 1$ on inside the unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to use Rouche's theorem to determine the number of zeros of $e^z - z - 1$ in the unit disk, but I cannot seem to get the right functions to apply Rouche's.

Comment: Isn't Rouche's theorem for polynomials ? Perhaps , you can use truncated taylor expansions.

Comment: @Peter : Rouché works for all holomorphic function, in its extended version also all meromorphic functions. This function is entire, so no proble to apply this.

Comment: *Hint*: Compared with the next term in the series for $e^z$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply Rouché's theorem to $f(z) = e^z-1-z$ and $g(z) =z^2/2$: For $|z| = 1$ is
$$
 |f(z)-g(z)| = \left| \sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}\right| \le \sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} = e - \frac 52 < \frac 12 = |g(z)|
$$
so that $f$ and $g$ have the same number of zeros in the unit disk.

---

But Rouché's theorem is actually not needed here, only the triangle inequality:
$$
 f(z) = \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!} = z^2 \left( \frac12 + \sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{z^{n-2}}{n!}\right)
$$
has a double zero at the origin, and the second factor has no zero in the unit disk since
$$
\left|\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{z^{n-2}}{n!}\right| \le \sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} = e - \frac 52 < \frac 12
$$
for $|z| \le 1$.